# Is this vector field a gradient field?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vector-analysis

let $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function. Then, consider the vector field

$$v(x) :=\Im(f\nabla \overline{f}).$$

My question is: Is this vector field a gradient field, i.e. does there exist in general a smooth function $g:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $v(x)=\nabla g(x)$?

My thoughts:
I remember that it suffices to compute the curl of $v$? Could this be an approach? However, I am not sure how the curl interacts with the imaginary part.

Following the strategy proposed in the comments, we have for $f=u+iv$ that

$$\Im(f \nabla \overline{f})= \Im((u +iv)(\nabla u-i\nabla v))= (v \nabla u- u \nabla v)$$

Comment: Write $f=u+iv$ with $u,v$ real-valued and smooth. Can you compute $\mathfrak{I}(f\nabla\overline{f})$ in terms of $u,v,\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$? I think the situation becomes much clearer in these terms.

Comment: What do you get for $v(x,y)$ if $f(x,y) = x+iy$?